# Feature extraction for document clustering

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, extract

I am using script from http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/document_clustering.html    for feature extraction through clustering.

The input is news data that will be clustered and news categories that are used as labels. The output is centroids with top words from news.
How can I connect each centroid with news categories that was entered in the beginning? What is the purpose of inputting categories (labels) in this example?  Clustering is unsupervised method and does not need labels but in this example the labels are used.

I am looking for a way to extract topics but want to see how they differ for different labels?
Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit more. I am not able to understand this. In the linked tutorial, the true labels were used just to compute metrics, nothing else.

Comment: Vivek thanks for your answer. I now understand it more.  I thought the labels were used for something else.